# in 80486 (kernel mode) what does out [dx],al do? ( from exam)

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel

we were asked what would the command `out [dx],al` would do?

what I have found online is about `out dx,al` are both legal?

I know that `out` sends what is in `al` to the PORT that is in `dx`. The question is if sending to the value inside of `dx` would work the same as sending to the address of `dx` (assuming that the value inside of `dx` is the same as its address).

Comment: This isn't going to fool any assembler, it just ignores the brackets.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such instruction, tell your prof he's got a typo.

`out dx, al` is the correct one.

Comment: we are allowed to write illegal instruction. But why would it not work?

Comment: The processor does not support going to a port number defined by the contents of a memory address.

Comment: What's more, `[dx]` is not a valid effective address. `[bx]`, `[si]`, `[di]`, or `bp]` might work. `[edx]` might work (but not with `out`, as Brian points out). I would expect `[dx]` to generate an error message from your assembler. What happens if you try it?